# Removing Class from all children except clicked child on ng-click in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I have a simple list item being parsed with ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="commonClass" ng-class="{'on': on_var}" ng-click="on_var=!on_var"> 
   {{item.name}} 
    <li>
</ul>
```

clicking on a list-item will add the class name 'on' as expected. but I want to remove all other 'on' classes as soon as you click on another list-item and only add it to the one clicked. I come from a jQuery background and I am new to angular. All I want to do is something like this:

```
$("li.commanClass").click(function(){ 
    $("li.commonClass").removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
})
```

I want to know what is the "angular way" of achieving this result

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du7aN/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In angular you want to pass object references to child scopes as much as possible. This way you can use prototypical object inheritance that can branch down many levels.

Think of a scope as being a `model`. In the case of `ng-repeat` it creates a child scope for each element. So if the parent scope holds a model it will be passed as reference to the child scopes. Each of these child scopes will hold a reference to the parent scope model object.

Thus you can do:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in model.items" 
    ng-class="{'on': model.selected==item}" 
    ng-click="model.selected=item">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

Then in controller:

```
$scope.model = {
        selected: null,
        items = [
            {name: "Apple"}, 
            {name: "Banana"}, 
            {name: "California"}
         ]
    };
```

Try to avoid using functions as above answer does. These functions will get called many times and will add unnecessary extra overhead.

**Valuable post to read:  ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)**

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JfeLz/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! All answers provided seem to work, but I like this one the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a variable to your scope to maintain which item is selected, and a function on your scope that toggles the variable.

Controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = 
    [
        {name: "Apple"},
        {name: "Banana"},
        {name: "California"}
    ]

    $scope.selectItem = function( item ) {
        $scope.selectedItem = item;
    };
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="commonClass" ng-class="{'on': selectedItem === item}" ng-click="selectItem(item)">
            {{ item.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle coming at ya of jsparks answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/eHDTF/

```
See fiddle for code!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer a directive for whole your project instead of controller.

```
<div class="nav-item">
    <ul>
        <li active-me="on">Item 1</li>
        <li active-me="on">Item 2</li>
        <li active-me="on">Item 3</li>
        <li active-me="on">Item 4</li>
        <li active-me="on">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then create activeMe directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('activeMe', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            activeMe: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                if (scope.activeMe !== undefined && scope.activeMe.trim().length > 0) {
                    element.parent().children().removeClass(scope.activeMe);
                    element.addClass(scope.activeMe);
                } else {
                    element.parent().children().removeClass('active');
                    element.addClass('active');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```